# Android TableLayout: Stretch one column and have two with equal width

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, tablelayout, android-tablelayout

I need something like [this, where two columns have the same width (0 and 2) and another one stretches to fill the remaining space (col 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gF7kT.png). However, the content of the two equal cols changes frequently, so sometimes the first columns would be larger than the other one and vice versa. My first idea was to use a TableLayout and `android:layout_weight`, but this didn't help much as I set `android:layout_weight="1"` and `android:layout_weight="2"` for the middle one.

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/firstRow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="2" />
</TableRow>
```

Is there a way to do this just using a layout or programatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ContraintLayout` with horizontal chain using `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight` attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="2.5"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/3"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/1"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="5"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/2"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="2.5"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I was not specific enough.
The left and right text views should have a flexible width which is the maximum needed by both.

`|abcde|----middle----|   2   |`